# Excel PowerQuery only returns 100 rows for JSON Import

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

How do I load the full dataset (490 rows) from JSON using Excel PowerQuery? It is currently only loading 100 rows.

**Import JSON:**

[image]

**Click on list (note the *TotalRecordCount* of 490 rows):**

[image]

**Only 100 rows displayed/in working set:**

[image]

(After this I convert into a table and then expand the columns, still with 100 rows).

Comment: Can you share the file?

Comment: TotalRecordCount might be incorrect or expect you to paginate if it comes from an API

Answer (score 0):

@Davide Bacci's answer above is correct - the data came from an API, which defaulted to a **page size of 100**, whilst reporting TotalRecordCount. I incorrectly assumed it was a PowerQuery issue.

Comment: Glad you sorted it